# Как вставить условие?

Tags: jquery

Как вставить сюда условие?

```
   $("#EmailAddress").val() + "как вставить сюда условие? типа if($(#EmailAddress2).val()){print "@@@"}" + $("#EmailAddress2").val()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что мешает сделать так?

```
var exp = '';
if ($(#EmailAddress2).val())
    var exp = '@@@';
var string =  $("#EmailAddress").val() + exp + $("#EmailAddress2").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
условие ? значение1 : значение2
```

http://learn.javascript.ru/ifelse#оператор-вопросительный-знак    - это то, что вам нужно?